# search a pattern from a unix directory

Tags: grep

I want to find whether any script in one unix directory is using one particular table as `"select *"` or not. Means I want to find `"select * from tablename"`. Now after select there can be any number of space or newline like `"select <any number of space or newline> * <any number of space or newline> from <any number of space or newline> tablename"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
 select
    *
  from

  tablename
```

Using grep:

```
$ grep -z 'select\s*[*]\s*from\s*tablename' -- file
 select
    *
  from

  tablename
```

`-z` tells to treat the input as NUL-separated.  Since no sensible text file contains NUL characters, this has the effect of reading in the whole file at once.  That allows us to search over multiple lines.  (If the file is too big for memory, we would want to think about another approach.)  To protect against file names which begin with `-`, the `--` is used to tell grep to stop option processing.

To obtain just the names of the matching files in the current directory:

```
grep -lz 'select\s*[*]\s*from\s*tablename' -- *
```

`*` tells grep to look at all files in the directory.  `-l` tells grep to just print the names of matching files and not the matching text.

#### More on the need for --

Let's consider a directory with one file:

```
$ ls
-l-
```

Now, lets run a grep command:

```
$ grep 'regex' *
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

The problem here is that grep interprets the file name as two options: `l` and `-`.  Since the second is not a legal option, it reports an error.  To protect against this, we need to use `--`.  The following will run without error:

```
grep 'regex' -- *
```

Comment: @KoushikChandra No problem.  I added that to the answer.

Comment: getting error `grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.`

Comment: Also TAB and NEW LINE considered in your grep?

Comment: @KoushikChandra Thank you for including the error message.  That error message indicates that there was a misplaced `-` on the command line.  Also, yes, `\s` matches all whitespace, not just blanks but also tabs and newlines.  From the sample file that I created, you can see that it works with newlines.

Comment: @KoushikChandra Sorry that you are having problems.  As a test, I just copied and pasted the commands from this answer to my command line and they all work for me.  The only way that I could come up with the error message that you see was if mis-copied it.  Please _copy and paste_ the command to your shell and try again.  If that doesn't work, please tell me more about which OS and which shell you are using and show me __exactly__ which command you are having trouble with.

Comment: I am getting the same error. The OS version I am using Linux development001 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 23 12:55:32 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @KoushikChandra OK. That appears to be some RedHat/CENTOS variant.  That should be good.  I can get the exact error that you report if I run the command with _too many dashes_ like `grep -lz- 'regex' *`.   Without the extra dash, it runs fine for me.  _Are you running exactly the command shown in the answer?_  If so, I am running out of ideas.

Comment: @KoushikChandra OK.  Let's try process of elimination.  Try `grep 'regex' *` and `grep -l 'regex' *' and `grep -z 'regex' *` and let me know which ones give you the "invalid option" error.

Comment: grep 'regex' * => this gives me invalid option

Comment: @KoushikChandra Interesting.  Try `grep 'regex' -- *` and let me know if it gives an error.

Comment: @KoushikChandra Excellent.  Now, let's try: `grep -lz 'select\s*[*]\s*from\s*tablename' -- *`

Comment: Yes it is working good. But can the directories be excluded? Means within a directories the command will only look into files and ignore if there are many other directories

Comment: Very good!  Yes, directories can be skipped: `grep -lzd skip 'select\s*[*]\s*from\s*tablename' -- *`

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Could you please update the answer, so that I can accept it; and provide a small explanation how this this working.